# Double quote does not recognised as punctuation in Python 2.7?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, token, nltk, punctuation

I have a question about **string.punctuation**.

I'm using NLTK and I need to clear my text from punctuation (the text is already divided in tokens with function `word_tokenize(my_str)`).

I wrote simple functions to do the work, but after calling these functions, I see that ***double quotes*** tokens remain! The others, like comma, full stop and other special is correctly clear, but not double quote. Why?
If I print string.punctuation in Python interpreter I read the list of char considered punctuation, so also double quote:

```
 >>>import string
 >>>print string.punctuation 
    !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

My functions are this:

```
def is_punct_char(char):
    return char in string.punctuation

def is_not_punct_char(char):
    return not is_punct_char(char)

# clear punct: 
#\par:    lista di token
#\return: lista di bigrammi (token, PoS)
def erase_punct(token_list):
    return filter(is_not_punct_char, token_list)
```

The original text is:

> Hello, how are you?
>       I'm ok, thanks. And you?
>       Not very "well".

After tokenization the output is:

> [u'Hello', u',', u'how', u'are', u'you', u'?', u'I', u"'m", u'ok',
>   u',', u'thanks', u'.', u'And', u'you', u'?', u'Not', u'very', u'``',
>   u'well', u"''", u'.']

After clear from punctuation the output is:

> [u'Hello', u'how', u'are', u'you', u'I', u"'m", u'ok', u'thanks',
>   u'And', u'you', u'Not', u'very', u'``', u'well', u"''"]

That is not correct. As last token I expected `u'well'`, not the two "around it" (``` u'``' ``` and `u"''"`).

Anyone could help me ?

Comment: And as to why your method doesn't work: your test only works for *single character strings*, but your two remaining tokens contain two characters each.

Comment: So you told me that `"` is considering as two character ?

Comment: Yes, it is two `'` single quote characters. `len(u"''")` -> 2.

Comment: Than i NEED to consider punctuation tokens, and THEN I have to delete it, because I need to pass to another function how many tokens I have (include punct tokens). After passing the num of toks I have to delete puncs tokens.
So I don't think that this question is exactly as the other you address me, in my opinion.